flutter_native_splash does not work on web
i am using the package flutter_native_splash in my app and it works fine on android but when i switch to chrome the page freezes and remain white , the problem is that i have no errors so i don't even know where to start from and no one has faced the same problem.
i got the dependency in pubspec.yaml and this is the settings for the splash screen:
`flutter_native_splash:
color: "#FFFFFF"
color_dark: "#000000"
image: assets/logos/t-store-splash-logo-black.png
image_dark: assets/logos/t-store-splash-logo-white.png
android_12:
color: "#FFFFFF"
color_dark: "#000000"
image: assets/logos/t-store-splash-logo-black.png
image_dark: assets/logos/t-store-splash-logo-white.png
web: true`
i used the command flutter pub run flutter_native_splash:create to initiate it.
i tried to find similar problems but none of their solutions worked for me.

use this command:
dart run flutter_native_splash:create

